# Formatting a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

I have an internal hard drive that I have ubuntu installed on. I also have an internal SSD card that I have windows installed on. I would like to put a NTFS partition on the hard drive with ubuntu on it (so I can access it while I am on my SSD card).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_cd), both because in this way you don't boot the other OS and because, being usually based on Linux, they are able to recognize pretty much every file system and therefore every partition that you have on your hard disk.

Usually the most suggested distro for this kind of things is [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), I don't think you can find a better tool.

Comment: @Benjamin you're welcome :)